# TPPDF Landscape document

Tags: ios, pdf

I am using TPPDF to generate a PDF in swift. How do you create a PDF in landscape mode. I found the variable "landscapeSize" in PDFPageFormat but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either create a `PDFDocument` using the `format` option, or as an alternative pass a full `layout`.
Therefore the easiest way is probably the following:

```swift
let document = PDFDocument(format: .a4)
var layout = PDFPageFormat.a4.layout
layout.size = PDFPageFormat.a4.landscapeSize
let document = PDFDocument(layout: layout)
```